# Can we migrate “note board” comments from one farm to another, without actually migrating whole user profile service application

Tags: user-profile

we are migrating from one farm to other farm SharePoint 2010 and we are having a site (XYZ) where we utilized note board feature. Now the other farm is not allowing us to migrate the user profile and we are in need of migrating note board comments from their without actually migrating whole user profile service application. Is this possible and how can I go for achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported method is to migrate the User Profile Service Databases together - you can't do them separately.  All your noteboard entries are stored in the UserProfile Social Database.

You could try:

1. Use API to query the user profile service and export the required values and then re-import them into destination farm.
2. Attempt to use only the social database
3. Manually export and import SQL records (not supported by Microsoft, nor recommended in general)

For #1 - SharePoint has an API, and you would want to look at the GetComments method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee578375.aspx )

I am not aware of any 3rd party migration products (MetaLogix, AvePoint, ShareGate, etc) that would meet your needs either.

for #2

You would have to delete your current user profile service.  Keep your current databases, but pull in your social database from the other farm.  Recreate your service using the older databases, but point to the new social database.  I have no idea if that will work or not.  In a production environment, i would be pretty Leary of using this method, as it could lead to other problems down the road.

for #3

Your pretty much on your own here.  It's not supported, but you could access and query the database directly and then insert those records into your database.

Comment: Hi Jesus those are really a valuable points which you have mentioned am not at all aware of those three points you have mentioned. I will look into those options and see further . Thank you.